# Issues with str_replace

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, str-replace

First, the string is being pulled from an XML file.

There's a special character that I am trying to replace: '£'

When I use str_replace like so:

```
$ability1 = str_replace("£", "", $ability);
```

This is what var_dump shows:

```
string(138) "Argothian Pixies can't be blocked by artifact creatures.�Prevent all damage that would be dealt to Argothian Pixies by artifact creatures."
```

Once $ability1 is passed and wordpress inserts it into the post. This is the result.

```
Argothian Pixies can’t be blocked by artifact creatures.
```

It deletes everything after the � character.

Why would £ be changed to � when its supposed to be "". I'm not quite sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your string is in UTF-8? PHP. You would have to do something like this:

```
$ability1 = utf8_decode($ability);
$ability1 = preg_replace("/[£ ]/","", $ability1);
$ability1 = utf8_encode($ability1);
```

Comment: Yep that was it. I had read about that the other day but it had slipped my mind, lol. preg_replace caused it to delete everything and only leave the special character. Ended up using:

    $ability1 = utf8_decode($ability);
    $ability1 = str_replace("£"," ", $ability1);
    $ability1 = utf8_encode($ability1);

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. There was a "not" (the ^) in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the string is using the correct encoding, try [encoding](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php) or [decoding](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php) to UTF8 and then apply the str_replace.

Answer (score 1):

How is the XML file encoded? I suspect it may be UTF-8. In which case you'll need to see a function such as utf_decode() to handle it correctly in your code (assuming your code is in ANSI)